# using NOT LIKE for parenthesis

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

here is my expression:

```
=([Panels] not Like '*IT_AMPH,*' and [Panels] not Like '*AMPH_SN,*' and [Panels] not Like '*AMPH_S,*')
```

can i say this instead:

```
= not ([Panels] Like '*IT_AMPH,*' Or [Panels] Like '*AMPH_SN,*' Or [Panels] Like '*AMPH_S,*')
```

are these expressions the same?

*****i need to mention that my question is not about logic it is about whether access will take this syntax*****

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep. This is just de Morgan's law. I had to think a bit about the effect of NULLS but in both versions if [Panels] IS NULL then the end result will be unknown.

In answer to your clarified question. Yes as well. I added a new "Yes/No" column to the Northwind Customers table called "TF" and both the following statements had the same effect.

```
UPDATE Customers SET 
TF = not ([Last Name] Like '*A*' Or 
          [Last Name] Like '*B*' Or 
          [Last Name] Like '*C*');

UPDATE Customers SET 
TF = ([Last Name] not Like '*A*' and 
      [Last Name] not Like '*B*' and 
      [Last Name] not Like '*C*');
```

Comment: +1 the predicates are equivalent. Picky point, though: in Access, expressions with `NULL` can return an actual `NULL` value rather than being restricted to a logical UNKNOWN result. For example (and using proprietary keyword `ALIKE`, otherwise the wildcard character changes depending on ANSI Query Mode used) this `SELECT NULL ALIKE '%A%';` returns `NULL` cast as a binary value, whereas `SELECT NULL ALIKE '%';` returns zero cast as a `SMALLINT`. Things quickly get weird in Access e.g. `SELECT NULL IN (1);` returns `NULL` whereas `SELECT 1 IN (NULL);` returns zero!

Answer (score 3):

(NOT A) AND (NOT B) is the same as NOT (A OR B), and this extends to more than two terms.  However - sometimes NULL handling can trip you up on this.  If you've no NULLs in [Panels] then all will be well, otherwise, test.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Can't see why not